# Oracle SQL. What statement should I use

Tags: sql, oracle, gaps-and-islands

DATA given:

```
 inventory_num_id        inventory_group_id             num   code
         9681066                 100003894             211      E
         9679839                 100003894             212      E
         9687165                 100003894             213      E
         9680883                 100003894             214      I
         9710863                 100003894             515      E
         9681246                 100003894             516      E
         9682695                 100003894             517      E
         9681239                 100003894             518      E
         9685409                 100003894             519      E
         9679843                 100003894             520      C
         9679844                 100003894             521      C
         9714882                 100003894             522      E
         9679845                 100003894             523      I
         9681211                 100003894             524      E
         9681216                 100003894             525      E
         9682696                 100003894             526      E
         9681227                 100003894             527      E
```

Result examples should be like:

```
inventory_group_id   code start  end 
------------------   ---- -----  ---- 
         100003894      E   211   213
         100003894      I   214
         100003894      E   515   519
         100003894      C   520   521
         100003894      E   522
         100003894      I   523
         100003894      E   524   527
```

What operator should I use to make start as minimum and end as max value? And could you please explain what I should do when the end(maximum)is not supposed to present?

Can I use GROUP BY clause there somehow?

Comment: how do you identify the start and end?

Comment: @bluefeet: I think it's when the code changes (ordered by num).

Comment: Result examples of **what**? What are you actually trying to do? [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: This is the islands problem; its solution depends on which database you are using (SQL Server/Oracle/MySQL/...)

Comment: As I think START starts at the beginning uninterrupted chain of same letters and it ends with a new letter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ann, be careful on the dark side of sql. 
There are more than one way to do it. 
Here is the answer:**

```
SELECT a.inventory_group_id,
   a.code,
  a.num        AS "start",
  decode(b.num,a.num,null,b.num) AS "end" FROM
  ( SELECT inventory_num_id,inventory_group_id,code,num
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY inventory_group_id,code ORDER BY num) AS rn
    FROM inventory_num  a
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
          ( SELECT * 
            FROM inventory_num  prev
            WHERE prev.inventory_group_id = a.inventory_group_id
            and  PREV.CODE = a.code
              AND prev.num = a.num - 1
          ) 
  )  a
JOIN
  ( SELECT  inventory_num_id,inventory_group_id,code, num 
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY inventory_group_id,code ORDER BY num) AS rn
    FROM inventory_num  a
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
          ( SELECT * 
            FROM inventory_num  next
            WHERE next.inventory_group_id = a.inventory_group_id
            and  next.CODE = a.code
              AND next.num = a.num + 1
          )
  )  b
ON  b.inventory_group_id = a.inventory_group_id and b.code = a.code
AND b.rn  = a.rn
order by 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tested this under MS Sql server and I bet it will work under oracle too:

```
select max(inventory_group_id) inventory_group_id,max(code) Code ,min(num) minNum,max(num) maxNum

from
(
select inventory_group_id,inventory_num_id,code,num,
      (select min(num) from DATA where num>
             (select max(num) from DATA where DATA.num<a.num and code<>a.code) 
      ) as minNum
from DATA a
) A

group by minNum
order by 3
```

Answer (score 1):

As gelonsoft noted, there are many ways to do this. I'd prefer to only hit the table once though. This is my current favourite, based on a method I first found on this site, probably on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4324654/266304) (and you might find many more approaches [among these questions](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/gaps-and-islands/hot):

```
select inventory_group_id, code, start_num,
    case when end_num = start_num then null else end_num end as end_num
from (
    select inventory_group_id, code, min(num) as start_num, max(num) as end_num
    from (
        select inventory_group_id, num, code,
            row_number() over (order by num)
              - row_number() over (partition by code order by num) as chain
        from inventory_num
    )
    group by inventory_group_id, code, chain
)
order by 1,3;

INVENTORY_GROUP_ID C  START_NUM    END_NUM
------------------ - ---------- ----------
         100003894 E        211        213
         100003894 I        214
         100003894 E        515        519
         100003894 C        520        521
         100003894 E        522
         100003894 I        523
         100003894 E        524        527
```

The inner select is doing all the work, by creating artificial groupings based on the `code` and `num` values - run that on its own to see what it's doing. The next query out is collapsing the groups to find the lowest and highest `num` for each of the artificial groups. The final outer query is purely to make the `end` value `null` if the chain only has one link - i.e. the `start` and `end` are the same - which you mentioned you wanted.

What you haven't said is whether the `num` values have to be contiguous. If I add a record with `code='I'` and `num=216`, I get the same number of outputs, but `214-216` is treated as one chain, even though there is no `215` value in between:

```
INVENTORY_GROUP_ID C  START_NUM    END_NUM
------------------ - ---------- ----------
         100003894 E        211        213
         100003894 I        214        216
...
```

I haven't figured out how to adapt this `row_number()` method to take account of that and treat them as separate chains - I'd be interested to see if it can be done while keeping it simple. The same thing happens with the other answers given; but I'm not sure if it matters to you.

If it does, here's another version which only hits the table once; rather more convoluted and in this form has the same potential problem with non-contiguous `num` values:

```
select distinct inventory_group_id, code,
    case
        when prev_code = code then lag(num) over (order by rn)
        else num
    end as start_num,
    case
        when next_code != code and prev_code != code then null
        when next_code = code then lead(num) over (order by rn)
        else num
    end as end_num
from (
    select inventory_group_id, num, code, prev_code, next_code,
        rownum as rn
    from (
        select inventory_group_id, num, code,
            lag(code) over (partition by inventory_group_id
                order by num) as prev_code,
            lead(code) over (partition by inventory_group_id
                order by num) as next_code
        from inventory_num
    )
    where (prev_code is null or code != prev_code)
        or (next_code is null or code != next_code)
    order by 1,2,3
)
order by 1,3,2;

INVENTORY_GROUP_ID C  START_NUM    END_NUM
------------------ - ---------- ----------
         100003894 E        211        213
         100003894 I        214
         100003894 E        515        519
         100003894 C        520        521
         100003894 E        522
         100003894 I        523
         100003894 E        524        527
```

The inner query selects from the table, and uses the `lead` and `lag` [analytic functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm) to find the code either side of each row.

The next query out excludes any rows that have the *same* code as both the next and previous rows; that is, anything that's in the middle of an uninterrupted chain. That means each chain is collapsed to at most two rows, with the start and end `num` values for that chain.

The `case` statement in the outer query make both rows for each chain look the same, by using `lead` and `lag` again; if there is only one row (e.g. for `214`) the first `when` clause of the second `case` makes the end value `null`, which you said you wanted. The `distinct` then removes the duplicates the `case` created.

I suggest you run each level of the query separately to see what it's doing, and understand what it's doing to the previous one.

As I said, this has the same potential problem if I introduce a row with `code='I'` and `num=216`:

```
INVENTORY_GROUP_ID C  START_NUM    END_NUM
------------------ - ---------- ----------
         100003894 E        211        213
         100003894 I        214        216
...
```

This can be split into two chains by adapting this method, but it's a little more complicated as you have to track and compare the `num` values as well as the `code` values:

```
select distinct inventory_group_id, code,
    case
        when prev_num is null then num
        when prev_code = code then lag(num) over (order by rn)
        else num
    end as start_num,
    case
        when next_code != code and prev_code != code then null
        when next_code is null then num
        when next_num is null then null
        when next_code = code then lead(num) over (order by rn)
        else num
    end as end_num
from (
    select inventory_group_id, num, code, prev_code, next_code,
        case
            when prev_num != num - 1 then null
            else prev_num
        end as prev_num,
        case
            when next_num != num + 1 then null
            else next_num
        end as next_num,
        rownum as rn
    from (
        select inventory_group_id, num, code,
            lag(code) over (partition by inventory_group_id
                order by num) as prev_code,
            lead(code) over (partition by inventory_group_id
                order by num) as next_code,
            lag(num) over (partition by inventory_group_id
                order by num) as prev_num,
            lead(num) over (partition by inventory_group_id
                order by num) as next_num
        from inventory_num
    )
    where (prev_code is null or code != prev_code)
        or (next_code is null or code != next_code)
        or (prev_num is null or num != prev_num + 1)
        or (next_num is null or num != next_num - 1)
    order by 1,2,3
)
order by 1,3,2;

INVENTORY_GROUP_ID C  START_NUM    END_NUM
------------------ - ---------- ----------
         100003894 E        211        213
         100003894 I        214
         100003894 I        216
         100003894 E        515        519
         100003894 C        520        521
         100003894 E        522
         100003894 I        523
         100003894 E        524        527
```