# Transform single date values into date interval

Tags: sql, oracle, gaps-and-islands

I need a query which adds up single date rows (not necesarilly continuous) into intervals taking into account the id of an object.

I have a select query, which returns following data

```
 id       date
9465    12/12/20
9465    12/12/21
9465    12/12/22
9465    12/12/25
9465    12/12/26
9466    12/12/21
9466    12/12/22
9466    12/12/23
9466    12/12/24
9466    12/12/25
9466    12/12/27
```

I need a query, which with use of above as a sub-query will output the data like this:

```
 id     date_from     date_till
9465    12/12/20      12/12/22
9465    12/12/25      12/12/26
9466    12/12/21      12/12/25
9466    12/12/27      12/12/27
```

Comment: Why did someone down vote??? If you ask me this is a good question, and I agree about oracle analytical functions, have a look at them, they are very powerful.

Comment: @sinisa229mihajlovski: My guess is that someone downvoted because the question contains no hint that the OP has tried anything at all. That makes the question look like "Please do my work for me", regardless of whether that's *actually* the case.

Answer (score 3):

we can do this with a couple of analytics:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='yy/mm/dd';

Session altered.

SQL> select id, min(val) date_from, max(val) date_till
  2    from (select id, val, max(grp) over(partition by id order by val) grp
  3             from (select id, val, lag(val, 1) over(partition by id order by val),
  4                           case
  5                             when lag(val, 1) over(partition by id order by val) < val - 1 then
  6                              row_number() over(partition by id order by val)
  7                             when row_number() over(partition by id order by val) = 1 then
  8                              1
  9                           end grp
 10                      from mytab))
 11   group by id, grp
 12   order by id, date_from
 13  /

        ID DATE_FRO DATE_TIL
---------- -------- --------
      9465 12/12/20 12/12/22
      9465 12/12/25 12/12/26
      9466 12/12/21 12/12/25
      9466 12/12/27 12/12/27
```

i.e. first we break the result set into groups where a group is defined as contigious dates for a given ID. We do this by checking the prior date and seeing if its < the current rows date - 1 with `lag(val, 1) over(partition by id order by val)`

```
SQL> select id, val, lag(val, 1) over(partition by id order by val),
  2         case
  3           when lag(val, 1) over(partition by id order by val) < val - 1 then
  4            row_number() over(partition by id order by val)
  5           when row_number() over(partition by id order by val) = 1 then
  6            1
  7         end grp
  8    from mytab
  9  /

        ID VAL      LAG(VAL,        GRP
---------- -------- -------- ----------
      9465 12/12/20                   1
      9465 12/12/21 12/12/20
      9465 12/12/22 12/12/21
      9465 12/12/25 12/12/22          4
      9465 12/12/26 12/12/25
      9466 12/12/21                   1
      9466 12/12/22 12/12/21
      9466 12/12/23 12/12/22
      9466 12/12/24 12/12/23
      9466 12/12/25 12/12/24
      9466 12/12/27 12/12/25          6

11 rows selected.
```

we need to fill in the blanks next so that the blanks associate the non-null group that preceeded it. i.e. we apply a max() to this with `max(grp) over(partition by id order by val)` the order by here means that we are only taking the max row seen up to that point and not the max across the whole set.

```
SQL> select id, val, max(grp) over(partition by id order by val) grp
  2    from (select id, val, lag(val, 1) over(partition by id order by val),
  3                  case
  4                    when lag(val, 1) over(partition by id order by val) < val - 1 then
  5                     row_number() over(partition by id order by val)
  6                    when row_number() over(partition by id order by val) = 1 then
  7                     1
  8                  end grp
  9             from mytab)
 10  /

        ID VAL             GRP
---------- -------- ----------
      9465 12/12/20          1
      9465 12/12/21          1
      9465 12/12/22          1
      9465 12/12/25          4
      9465 12/12/26          4
      9466 12/12/21          1
      9466 12/12/22          1
      9466 12/12/23          1
      9466 12/12/24          1
      9466 12/12/25          1
      9466 12/12/27          6

11 rows selected.
```

now its a simple group by (id, grp) to be applied, taking the min() and max() for each id+group.

Answer (score 2):

I like to solve this problem with a little trick that uses the anlytic functions.  If we enumerate each row, and then subtract that value from the date, the date is constant for things in sequence.  That is the "group" id.  Then it is a simple matter of aggregation:

```
select id, min(date) as date_from, max(date) as date_to
from (select (date - row_number() over (partition by id order by date)) as groupid,
             t.*
      from t
     ) 
group by id, groupid
```

The overall statement is pretty simple, too.

I usually use analytic functions for this.  However, it is possible that the following will work in Oracle, at least for data sets where the date arithmetic works:

```
select id, min(date) as date_from, max(date) as date_to
from (select (date - rownum) as groupid,
             t.*
      from t
      order by id, date
     ) 
group by id, groupid
```

Answer (score 0):

This is known as an "islands" problem. Here is an approach for an Oracle-based solution:

[Oracle SQL. What statement should I use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11785007/oracle-sql-what-statement-should-i-use)