# SQL Server 2008 group by only rows which are in sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want a similar solution as per [sql group by only rows which are in sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324623/sql-group-by-only-rows-which-are-in-sequence)

This is my data.

```
ID  SiteID  Latitude    Longitude
1   104 -6.197488   106.421873
2   823 -6.52733    106.849
3   823 -6.52733    106.849
4   823 -6.52733    106.849
5   823 -6.52733    106.849
6   823 -6.52733    106.849
7   104 -6.197488   106.421873
8   841 -6.30754    107.307
```

And I want to group record in same sequence only. E.g result (ID col doesn't really matter):

```
ID  SiteID  Latitude    Longitude
1   104 -6.197488   106.421873
6   823 -6.52733    106.849
7   104 -6.197488   106.421873
8   841 -6.30754    107.307
```

Tried following but it's not returning desired result.

```
        ;WITH YourTable AS
(
    SELECT ID, SiteID, Latitude, Longitude FROM @LatLng 
),
T AS
(
SELECT ID,
       SiteID,Latitude, Longitude,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SiteID ORDER BY ID) AS Grp
FROM YourTable
)
SELECT SiteID, Latitude, Longitude FROM T
GROUP BY SiteID,Latitude, Longitude, Grp
```

This is sample code to run above scenario :

```
  DECLARE @LatLng TABLE (ID  [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,SiteID nVARCHAR(50), Latitude float, Longitude float)
  INSERT INTO @LatLng(SiteID, Latitude, Longitude) VALUES ('104',1,106)
  INSERT INTO @LatLng(SiteID, Latitude, Longitude) VALUES ('823',-6,106)
   INSERT INTO @LatLng(SiteID, Latitude, Longitude) VALUES ('823',-6,106)
    INSERT INTO @LatLng(SiteID, Latitude, Longitude) VALUES ('823',-6,106)
 INSERT INTO @LatLng(SiteID, Latitude, Longitude) VALUES ('823',-6,106)
  INSERT INTO @LatLng(SiteID, Latitude, Longitude) VALUES ('104',1,106)
    INSERT INTO @LatLng(SiteID, Latitude, Longitude) VALUES ('814',-3,106)

  SELECT * FROM @LatLng

  ;with cte as(select *, row_number() over (partition by siteid order by id)as grp from @LatLng) select * from cte where grp=1
```

Comment: From the resultset you have shown, it looks like you need to group them by `SiteID` only. Possible solution: `;with cte as(select *, row_number() over (partition by siteid order by id)as grp from yourtable) select * from cte where grp=1`

Comment: Can you elaborate on *"isn't really working"*, this doesn't help much.

Comment: I have added above the sample code to run this.

Comment: @MartinSmith not if he orders by `ID` that is unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;
WITH    T AS ( SELECT   ID
                      , SiteID
                      , Latitude
                      , Longitude
                      , DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY ID )
                        - DENSE_RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY SiteID ORDER BY ID ) AS Grp
               FROM     @LatLng
             )
    SELECT  MAX(ID)
          , SiteID
          , Latitude
          , Longitude
    FROM    T
    GROUP BY SiteID
          , Latitude
          , Longitude
          , Grp
    ORDER BY MAX(ID)
```

Comment: Thanks Stuart, I need time to digest this now. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH T AS
(
   SELECT ID,  SiteID,Latitude, Longitude,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SiteID ORDER BY ID ASC) AS Grp
   FROM @LatLng 
)
SELECT SiteID, Latitude, Longitude 
FROM T
WHERE Grp = 1
```

Comment: How is this different from what they already have? (at the end of the code following "This is sample code to run above scenario")

Comment: @MartinSmith - It isn't, for some reason the OP added that in after I posted this.  I'm totally not clear what he wanted but I guess Stuart figured it out.

Comment: The groups the OP wants are based on the order by id. Ignoring sequential ones with the same `SiteId` the pattern of SiteIds is `104,823,104,841` notice that `104` appears twice.

Comment: @MartinSmith - I guess I'll have to test this later because this is what I'd expect my code to do -- show one row every time SiteID changes when ordered by ID.