# how to group data based on its sequence and group by other columns

Tags: sql, oracle, gaps-and-islands

I have a table with 3 columns c1,c2,c3 in Oracle like below:

```
c1  c2  c3
 1  34   2
 2  34   2
 3  34   2
 4  24   2
 5  24   2
 6  34   2
 7  34   2
 8  34   1
```

I need to group the `col1` and get the min and max number (of `col1`) based on its sequence, `col2` and `col3`.

i.e., I need the result as below:

```
c1_min  c1_max  c2  c3
     1       3  34   2
     4       5  24   2
     6       7  34   2
     8       8  34   1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it well, you want to group *consecutive* rows together. This is far from being trivial. Or at least, I can't find right now a *simple* way of doing it. For ease of understanding, I will break the query in several steps:

### Step 1:

The first thing is to identify your "groups" boundaries. Using the [`LAG`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions070.htm) analytic function might help you here:

```
CASE WHEN LAG("c2", 1) OVER(ORDER BY "c1") = "c2" 
      AND LAG("c3", 1) OVER(ORDER BY "c1") = "c3" 
     THEN 0 
     ELSE 1
END CLK,
T.* FROM T
ORDER BY "c1"
```

### Step 2:

The second step, is to number each of your groups. A simple [`SUM`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions163.htm) over partition will do the trick. That leads to:

```
SELECT SUM(CLK) OVER (ORDER BY "c1"
                      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING 
                      AND CURRENT ROW) GRP,
       V.* 
FROM (
  SELECT
    CASE WHEN LAG("c2", 1) OVER(ORDER BY "c1") = "c2" 
          AND LAG("c3", 1) OVER(ORDER BY "c1") = "c3" 
         THEN 0 
         ELSE 1
    END CLK,
    T.* FROM T
) V
ORDER BY "c1";
```

### Final step:

Finally, you can wrap that in a simple `GROUP BY` query to obtain the desired output:

```
SELECT MIN("c1"), MAX("c1"), "c2", "c3" FROM
(
    SELECT SUM(CLK) OVER (ORDER BY "c1"
                          ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING 
                          AND CURRENT ROW) GRP,
           V.* 
    FROM (
      SELECT
        CASE WHEN LAG("c2", 1) OVER(ORDER BY "c1") = "c2"
              AND LAG("c3", 1) OVER(ORDER BY "c1") = "c3"
             THEN 0 
             ELSE 1
        END CLK,
        T.* FROM T
    ) V
)
GROUP BY GRP, "c2", "c3"
ORDER BY GRP
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7d57c/10

Comment: i am using toad for running queries, when i run the above query. it gives me an error saying  ORA-00904: "c3": invalid identifier'

Comment: @Mars - Sylvain has quoted your identifiers, I guess because you showed them as lower-case in the query results. If they are not really quoted then just remove all of the double-quotes from the query.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways to approach a [gaps-and-islands problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands). As an alternative to Sylvain's `lag` version - not better, just different - you can use a trick with row numbers calculated analytically based on your grouping fields. This adds a 'chain' psuedocolumn to the table values, which will be unique for each contiguous group of `c2`/`c3` pairs:

```
select c1, c2, c3,
  dense_rank() over (partition by c2, c3 order by c1)
    - dense_rank() over (partition by null order by c1) as chain
from t42
order by c1, c2, c3;
```

(I can't take credit for this - I first saw it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324623/sql-group-by-only-rows-which-are-in-sequence/4324654#4324654)). You can then use that as an inline view to calculate your sum:

```
select min(c1) as c1_min, max(c1) as c1_max, c2, c3
from (
  select c1, c2, c3,
    dense_rank() over (partition by c2, c3 order by c1)
      - dense_rank() over (partition by null order by c1) as chain
  from t42
)
group by c2, c3, chain
order by c1_min;

    C1_MIN     C1_MAX         C2         C3
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          3         34          2 
         4          5         24          2 
         6          7         34          2 
         8          8         34          1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cd91b/2) showing the intermediate stage too.

You can use other analytic functions like `row_number()` instead of `dense_rank()`; they may give slightly different results for some data, but you get the [same result with this sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cd91b/1).

Comment: This answer solved my similar problem for SQL Server 2008 R2, which doesn't support the `LAG` function.