# identifying a period with particular characteristic using sql

Tags: sql, oracle, time-series

I am looking to write an SQL query that identifies the longest period that an individual has gone without having a meat meal. Ideally the output would look like

```
person  periodstart  periodend
```

where for each person the longest period without meat would be identified and

> **periodstart** would be the time of the first non-meat meal
>
> **periodend** would be the time of the first meat meal following.

SQL below creates table and data .

```
CREATE TABLE MEALS 
(
  PERSON VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) 
, MEALTIME DATE 
, FOODTYPE VARCHAR2(20) 
);

Insert into MEALS (PERSON,MEALTIME,FOODTYPE) 
values ('Jane',to_date('04-JAN-15 06:09:09','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),'fruit');
Insert into MEALS (PERSON,MEALTIME,FOODTYPE) 
values ('Jane',to_date('05-JAN-15 06:09:09','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),'veg');
Insert into MEALS (PERSON,MEALTIME,FOODTYPE) 
values ('Jane',to_date('07-JAN-15 06:01:24','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),'meat');
Insert into MEALS (PERSON,MEALTIME,FOODTYPE) 
values ('Jane',to_date('07-JAN-15 12:03:50','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),'veg');
Insert into MEALS (PERSON,MEALTIME,FOODTYPE) 
values ('John',to_date('02-JAN-15 10:03:23','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),'veg');
Insert into MEALS (PERSON,MEALTIME,FOODTYPE) 
values ('John',to_date('03-JAN-15 10:03:23','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),'meat');
Insert into MEALS (PERSON,MEALTIME,FOODTYPE) 
values ('John',to_date('04-JAN-15 10:03:23','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),'veg');
Insert into MEALS (PERSON,MEALTIME,FOODTYPE) 
values ('John',to_date('05-JAN-15 07:03:23','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),'veg');
Insert into MEALS (PERSON,MEALTIME,FOODTYPE) 
values ('John',to_date('05-JAN-15 10:03:23','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),'veg');
Insert into MEALS (PERSON,MEALTIME,FOODTYPE) 
values ('John',to_date('06-JAN-15 05:01:54','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),'veg');
Insert into MEALS (PERSON,MEALTIME,FOODTYPE) 
values ('John',to_date('06-JAN-15 05:01:54','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),'fruit');
Insert into MEALS (PERSON,MEALTIME,FOODTYPE) 
values ('John',to_date('06-JAN-15 10:03:23','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),'meat');
Insert into MEALS (PERSON,MEALTIME,FOODTYPE) 
values ('Mary',to_date('02-JAN-15 05:01:54','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),'veg');
Insert into MEALS (PERSON,MEALTIME,FOODTYPE) 
values ('Mary',to_date('03-JAN-15 06:04:25','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),'meat');
Insert into MEALS (PERSON,MEALTIME,FOODTYPE) 
values ('Mary',to_date('05-JAN-15 04:04:25','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),'veg');
Insert into MEALS (PERSON,MEALTIME,FOODTYPE) 
values ('Mary',to_date('05-JAN-15 06:04:25','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),'meat');
Insert into MEALS (PERSON,MEALTIME,FOODTYPE) 
values ('Mary',to_date('05-JAN-15 06:04:25','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),'meat');
Insert into MEALS (PERSON,MEALTIME,FOODTYPE) 
values ('Mary',to_date('06-JAN-15 05:01:54','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),'veg');
Insert into MEALS (PERSON,MEALTIME,FOODTYPE) 
values ('Mary',to_date('07-JAN-15 06:04:25','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),'veg');

commit;
```

Comment: Plus one for adding ddl and dml. This is rarely seen on SO, unfortunately.

Comment: A good way to ask a question, finally seen after a long time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem, and there are various ways to approach it. One is to use [an analytic function effect/trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324623/sql-group-by-only-rows-which-are-in-sequence/4324654#4324654) to finds the chains of contiguous periods for each type:

```
select person, mealtime, foodtype,
  case when foodtype = 'meat' then 'Yes' else 'No' end as meat,
  dense_rank() over (partition by person,
      case when foodtype = 'meat' then 1 else 0 end order by mealtime)
    - dense_rank() over (partition by person order by mealtime) as chain
from meals
order by person, mealtime;
```

The 'chain' pseudocolumn is based on a `case` here, as you want fruit and veg - or anything non-meat - treated the same.

You can then use that as an inner query to find the start of each meat and non-meat period, from the first meal in each chain:

```
select person, meat, min(mealtime) as first_meal
from (
  select person, mealtime, foodtype,
    case when foodtype = 'meat' then 'Yes' else 'No' end as meat,
    dense_rank() over (partition by person,
        case when foodtype = 'meat' then 1 else 0 end order by mealtime)
      - dense_rank() over (partition by person order by mealtime) as chain
  from meals
)
group by person, meat, chain
order by person, min(mealtime);

PERSON               MEAT FIRST_MEAL       
-------------------- ---- ------------------
Jane                 No   04-JAN-15 06:09:09 
Jane                 Yes  07-JAN-15 06:01:24 
Jane                 No   07-JAN-15 12:03:50 
John                 No   02-JAN-15 10:03:23 
...
```

You want the period to cover the first non-meat meal to the next meat-meal, so you can use *that* as an inner query with lead and lag to peek at the rows either side: for a veg period you peek ahead to see the start of the next meat period; for a meat period you peek back to see he start of the previous veg period:

```
select person, meat,
  case when meat = 'Yes' then lag(first_meal) over (partition by person
      order by first_meal) else first_meal end as period_start,
  case when meat = 'No' then lead(first_meal) over (partition by person
      order by first_meal) else first_meal end as period_end
from (
  select person, meat, min(mealtime) as first_meal
  from (
    select person, mealtime, foodtype,
      case when foodtype = 'meat' then 'Yes' else 'No' end as meat,
      dense_rank() over (partition by person,
          case when foodtype = 'meat' then 1 else 0 end order by mealtime)
        - dense_rank() over (partition by person order by mealtime) as chain
    from meals
  )
  group by person, meat, chain
)
order by person, period_start;

PERSON               MEAT PERIOD_START       PERIOD_END       
-------------------- ---- ------------------ ------------------
Jane                 No   04-JAN-15 06:09:09 07-JAN-15 06:01:24 
Jane                 Yes  04-JAN-15 06:09:09 07-JAN-15 06:01:24 
Jane                 No   07-JAN-15 12:03:50                    
John                 No   02-JAN-15 10:03:23 03-JAN-15 10:03:23 
...
```

That gives you duplicates, effectively, though I've left the 'meat' flag in to make it a bit clearer at this point. Assuming you want to ignore the latest open-ended period you just need to skip those and eliminate the duplicates:

```
select person, period_start, period_end
from (
  select person, meat,
    case when meat = 'Yes' then lag(first_meal) over (partition by person
        order by first_meal) else first_meal end as period_start,
    case when meat = 'No' then lead(first_meal) over (partition by person
        order by first_meal) else first_meal end as period_end
  from (
    select person, meat, min(mealtime) as first_meal
    from (
      select person, mealtime, foodtype,
        case when foodtype = 'meat' then 'Yes' else 'No' end as meat,
        dense_rank() over (partition by person,
            case when foodtype = 'meat' then 1 else 0 end order by mealtime)
          - dense_rank() over (partition by person order by mealtime) as chain
      from meals
    )
    group by person, meat, chain
  )
)
where meat = 'No'
and period_start is not null
and period_end is not null
order by person, period_start;

PERSON               PERIOD_START       PERIOD_END       
-------------------- ------------------ ------------------
Jane                 04-JAN-15 06:09:09 07-JAN-15 06:01:24 
John                 02-JAN-15 10:03:23 03-JAN-15 10:03:23 
John                 04-JAN-15 10:03:23 06-JAN-15 10:03:23 
Mary                 02-JAN-15 05:01:54 03-JAN-15 06:04:25 
Mary                 05-JAN-15 04:04:25 05-JAN-15 06:04:25
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0a5d6/1) with the intermediate steps in full.

Belatedly realised you only wanted the longest period for each person, which you can get with yet another layer:

```
select person, period_start, period_end
from (
  select person, period_start, period_end,
    rank() over (partition by person order by period_end - period_start desc) as rnk
  from (
    ...
  )
  where meat = 'No'
  and period_start is not null
  and period_end is not null
)
where rnk = 1
order by person, period_start;

PERSON               PERIOD_START       PERIOD_END       
-------------------- ------------------ ------------------
Jane                 04-JAN-15 06:09:09 07-JAN-15 06:01:24 
John                 04-JAN-15 10:03:23 06-JAN-15 10:03:23 
Mary                 02-JAN-15 05:01:54 03-JAN-15 06:04:25
```

[Updated SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0a5d6/2).

Answer (score 1):

solution is in SQL SERVER i hope that you can understand easily

```
with x as (
 select ROW_NUMBER()over( Partition by person order by MealTime) rowId,* from #MEALS
)
,y as (
select ROW_NUMBER() over( Partition by person order by MealTime) rowID, * from 
#MEALS where FOODTYPE='meat')
select x.PERSON,x.MEALTIME startdate,y.MEALTIME endDate,        datediff(second,x.MEALTIME,y.MEALTIME) diff from x 
left join 
y on x.PERSON=y.PERSON where 
x.rowId=1 and y.rowID=1
```

Comment: I hope I have converted to Oracle correctly. If I have I don't get the correct answer! It appears to return the first meat free period not the longest one. So I get                         Jane 04/01/2015 06:09:09 07/01/2015 06:01:24
John 02/01/2015 10:03:23 03/01/2015 10:03:23
Mary 02/01/2015 05:01:54 03/01/2015 06:04:25           for john this is the first period but not the longest one.