# SQL Group rows in sequence while advanced criteria are met

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, greatest-n-per-group, ranking

Given the following table with millions of log entries. Each log entry can be of kind = 0 (clearing) or kind = 1 (event). Clearing means that all preceding events are taken care of - so they can be grouped (in a view). All subsequent events must be grouped by their status and the latest date they occured.

WHILE or temp-tables are note really a solution with the size of this table. I looked into the [sql group by only rows which are in sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324623/sql-group-by-only-rows-which-are-in-sequence) but couldn't figure out a way to adapt it to the given problem.

**Edit 1:** Rearanged rows to highlight *clearing*

The given data table (*ordered by RelationId, ValidFrom DESC*)

```
Id|RelationId|Kind|StatusId| ValidFrom
--------------------------------------
10|         1|   1|      14|2015-01-06
9 |         1|   1|      14|2015-01-05
8 |         1|   1|      15|2015-01-05
7 |         1|   0|      12|2015-01-04 (clearing id 6,4)
6 |         1|   1|      13|2015-01-03 (.. cleared with id 7)
4 |         1|   1|      13|2015-01-02 (.. cleared with id 7)
3 |         2|   1|      19|2015-01-02
1 |         2|   0|      18|2015-01-01 (no clearing)
5 |         3|   0|      18|2015-01-03 (clearing id 2)
2 |         3|   1|      20|2015-01-02 (.. cleared with id 5)
--------------------------------------
```

The disired output is given in the table below. As you can see, the event count does not take the clearing row into account.

**Edit 2:** Added question to clearify

**Question:** What would be an efficent SQL query that outputs the following results?

```
RelationId|StatusId|Count|MaxValidFrom
--------------------------------------
1         |      14|    2|  2015-01-06
1         |      15|    1|  2015-01-05
1         |      12|    2|  2015-01-04
2         |      19|    1|  2015-01-02
3         |      18|    1|  2015-01-03
--------------------------------------
```

The SQL Server used is SQL 2008 R2 Enterprise.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why `statuid=13` is missing in output

Comment: @zingix Please post your SQL Statement

Comment: **@NoDisplayName** statusid=13 is hidden by the clearing row with id 4 (all previous events are grouped, independant of their status ids), **@Eli Ekstein** That is what I am looking for, an efficient SQL Statement which could solve this problem :)